# AutoHotKey: How to Count number of files in active folder and copy to clipboard?

Tags: autohotkey

I have a long list folders that i need to automatically spreadsheet the following two pieces of information into our existing excel document:

1. Folder Name
2. File count within that folder

I've written the script up to the point where i now need AHK to get the file count of the active explorer window, copy to clipboard and ALT+TAB/Paste it into the spreadsheet. I plan to loop this script using 'goto' and just monitoring it until it reaches the last folder and use ESC to end the script by eye.

Whats the easiest way to get the numerical value file count of the active window and have it copied to clipboard?

My code so far which is basically using F2 to 'rename' thus copy folder name, alt+tab to spreadsheet, paste it in, move to the file count cell on the spreadsheet, alt+tab back to active explorer window, step into said folder -- and now i'm stuck (where i need to get file count onto clipboard). It's worth noting that i would want the file count to ignore system files like .DS_Store if they're present.

```
`::

{

Send, {F2}
Sleep, 200
Send, {Ctrl Down}
Sleep, 50
Send, c
sleep, 50
Send, {Ctrl Up}
Sleep, 100
Send, {Alt Down}
Sleep, 50
Send, {Tab}
Sleep, 50
Send, {Alt Up}
Sleep, 100
Send, {Ctrl Down}
Sleep, 50
Send, v
sleep, 50
Send, {Ctrl Up}
Sleep, 100
Send, {Right}
Sleep, 50
Send, {Right}
Sleep, 50
Send, {Right}
Sleep, 100
Send, {Alt Down}
Sleep, 50
Send, {Tab}
Sleep, 50
Send, {Alt Up}
Sleep, 100
Send, {Enter}

^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Need my file count / copy to clipboard here


Esc::ExitApp

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe have a look at something like this (and follow along in the comments):

```
; Calculate the number of files in a folder and its subfolders:
SetBatchLines, -1  ; Make the operation run at maximum speed.
FileNum = 0
; FileSelectFolder, WhichFolder  ; Ask the user to pick a folder.
WhichFolder := Clipboard  ;  assumes full path to folder is in clipboard
Loop, Files, %WhichFolder%\*.*, R
{
    if A_LoopFileAttrib contains H,R,S  ; Skip Hidden, Read-only, or System files
        continue  ; Skip this file and move on to the next one
    FileNum += 1
}
Clipboard := FileNum
ClipWait  ; Wait for the clipboard to contain text.
MsgBox %WhichFolder% has %FileNum% files in it (incl. subfolders).
```

Then, have a look at the following which explains how to read and loop through directories and files:
https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/LoopFile.htm.

Hth, let us know how you make out . . .

Comment: That's great, it actually worked in the sense that it was able to copy the file count to clipboard when i selected the specified folder. But how would the code look if i just wanted it to run that task for the active explorer window? I've already stepped into the folder and wish to get the file count for the active window, then i can ask the script to step back a level in explorer, move down one and repeat the task on the folder below. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Ok, make sure you see my edits above which handle Read-Only, Hidden and System files.  Now, instead of asking the user for WhichFolder, while you are in the Explorer Window copy the full text name of the directory path (use ctrl+l to get to address bar, maybe ctrl-a to select all if needed, then ctrl+v to put it in clipboard) then use that to set WhichFolder to: WhichFolder := Clipboard

Comment: I've edited the answer with the above.  Just make sure your script has gotten the path name into the clipboard before getting to this part.  Then, you'll overwrite that clipboard with the new FileNum data, and you can go from there pasting it, going back to explorer and traversing to next dir and copying that address, and so on.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I'm a bit novice at AHK but i'm also quick to learn and I've definitely learned here. Will do more reading up on Loop to gain a deeper understanding of that function. Upvoted all your comments and finalised your answer for maximum rep. This has turned a daily administrative office task into a breeze! Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad it worked out!! And Big Thanks for pushing me over the 1K rep level!  8-)